# What is the "Python" way to parse through mroutes

Tags: python, networking

I am a network engineer who is trying to script out a specific "mroute" (multicast route) from some exported data. I am trying to figure out the most "pythonic" path to do this.

The data looks something like this (nothing specific to my network, just lab exports):

```
(*,224.0.0.0/4) RPF nbr: 96.34.35.36 Flags: C RPF P
  Up: 1w5d

(*,224.0.0.0/24) Flags: D P
  Up: 1w5d

(*,224.0.1.39) Flags: S P
  Up: 1w5d

(96.34.246.55,224.0.1.39) RPF nbr: 96.34.35.36 Flags: RPF
  Up: 1w4d
  Incoming Interface List
    Bundle-Ether434 Flags: F A, Up: 1w4d
  Outgoing Interface List
    BVI100 Flags: F, Up: 1w4d
    TenGigE0/0/0/3 Flags: F, Up: 1w4d
    TenGigE0/0/1/1 Flags: F, Up: 1w4d
    TenGigE0/0/1/2 Flags: F, Up: 1w4d
    TenGigE0/0/1/3 Flags: F, Up: 1w4d
    TenGigE0/1/1/1 Flags: F, Up: 1w4d
    TenGigE0/1/1/2 Flags: F, Up: 1w4d
    TenGigE0/2/1/0 Flags: F, Up: 1w4d
    TenGigE0/2/1/1 Flags: F, Up: 1w4d
    TenGigE0/2/1/2 Flags: F, Up: 1w4d
    Bundle-Ether234 (0/3/CPU0) Flags: F, Up: 2d17h
    Bundle-Ether434 Flags: F A, Up: 1w4d

(*,224.0.1.40) Flags: S P
  Up: 1w5d
  Outgoing Interface List
    TenGigE0/2/1/0 Flags: II, Up: 1w5d
```

I have tried to replicate C style for loops to move the index incrementer up when I regex certain lines.

The end result is I only want to show a multicast group if it has specific output in the "Outgoing" section.

A horrible example of what I have tried so far (not complete, the data is handed off in a list):

```
myarray = []
myarray = output.split("\n")

max_count = len(myarray)
i= 0
while (i < max_count):
    if (re.match(r"(^\()", myarray[i])):
        group = myarray[i]
        print group
        i+=1
        while (re.match(r'(?!^\()', myarray[i])):
            if (re.match(r"  Outgoing Interface List", myarray[i])):
                outgoing = myarray[i]
                print outgoing
                i+=1
                while (re.match(r'(?!^\()', myarray[i])):
                    print myarray[i]
                    i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
    else:
        i+=1
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Should "was" be "way" in the title?

Comment: Yep, corrected, thanks!

Comment: So, this works but you want to do it in a more Pythonic fashion? Maybe this should be on [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) then?

Comment: 1) `myarray[i]` `i+=1` - this is definitely ugly. you could use a state machine, or an object that allows to fetch a line. 2) count the indentation. lot of info in there.

Comment: Close to working fully but the problem is the code is getting less and less readable the farther down the rabbit hole I go.

Comment: `flat is better than nested`. In my opinion, an if-statement should deal with an exception, and terminate if need be. So rather than `if (re.match(r"(^\()", myarray[i])): group = myarray[i]`, do it the other way around: `if not (re.match(r"(^\()", myarray[i])): continue`. This eliminates another level of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop eliminates having to use a variable counter, since it already returns the sequence number while looping.

There's probably a simpler or better way still available to do it also, but here's just one way i thought of i hope you get the same results.

```
myarray = output.split("\n")

for i in range(len(myarray)):
    if re.match('(^\()', myarray[i]):
        group = myarray[i]
        print group
        if (re.match('(?!^\()', myarray[i])):
            if re.match('\s+Outgoing Interface List', myarray[i]):
                outgoing = myarray[i]
                print outgoing
                if re.match('(?!^\()', myarray[i]):
                    print myarray[i]
```

My results were:

```
(*,224.0.0.0/4)
(*,224.0.0.0/24)
(*,224.0.1.39)
(96.34.246.55,224.0.1.39)
(0/3/CPU0)
(*,224.0.1.40)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jclarke but the problem is I only want to show a group if it has a specific result in the outgoing group. That is why I was plying with a custom "list" index in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it is more pythonic, but i prefer to use iterator/generator instead of direct array indexing.

```
import re

def print_out_ifaces( group, iterator ):
    """
       function print output interfaces with its group (ip)
          It uses fact that you have empty line between 2 groups
    """
    for iface_list in iterator:
        iface_list = iface_list.rstrip()  #remove tail \n
        if not iface_list:
            return

        if not re.match( r" *Outgoing Interface List", iface_list ):
            continue

        print "group is " + group.rstrip()
        print iface_list # will print "Outgoing Interface List"
        for iface in iterator:
            iface = iface.rstrip(); #remove tail \n
            if not iface:
                print # add additional empty line beween 2 groups
                return
            print iface

output = open( 'routes', 'r' ); # i saved your routes example in file "routes"

#if your "output" is string with routes
#then after "split('\n')" run "iter( myarray )"

for line in output:
   if line.startswith( "(" ): # startswith much faster then checking first symbol by re
        group = line;
        print_out_ifaces( group, output )
```

Also it's possible to use special tools for parsing (like Pyparsing or PLY), but I think it will be overkill for this task.

Comment: Thanks Arnial. Going to read upon iterator/generators and see if I can get that to work. I believe that iterators has a "next" funtion/method built in so might be able to use that too.